# Route from one cxf service to another through camel

Tags: spring, cxf, apache-camel, cxfrs

I have a requirement where I am having a cxf rest service on which some data will be post. e.g.

`<data><FirstName>Hello</FirstName><LastName>World</LastName></data>`

I have to combine firstname and lastname as fullname e.g.

```
<data><fullname>Hello World</fullname></data>
```

and post it on another rest service which will process this FullName and generate a ID for this user. So for user the final output should be Id and Full name. e.g.

```
<output><id>123</id><fullname>Hello World</fullname></output>
```

I have two separate rest services working, but I want apache camel to invoke and route my first service automatically with its data to the second rest service.

So how can I do that? I didn't got any example where I can get the post data for firstname and last name and how to send fullname to another service? Any example or help very appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this example. I'm sure it will help you find what you're looking for -

A composite Rest service using Apache Camel
-Andrej Koelewijn

[Read this!](http://www.andrejkoelewijn.com/blog/2010/06/13/a-composite-rest-service-using-camel/)

Thanks.